# convex, twice differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, twice differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $c$ is a stationary point, then $c$ is a local minimum point.

I have gone round in circles with this question and am now completely lost and would appreciate any help given

Comment: In the first paragraph you seem to omit the existence of $c$ inside interval $(a,b)$, but rely on this fact in the second paragraph.  It would be better to state this more clearly in the beginning.

Comment: Your definition of local minima seems to be off. You are implicitly enforcing uniqueness on the minima. For e.g., $f(x)=42$ is a twice differentiable function on $(0,1)$ with $0.5$ (or any point in that interval) being a local minima. But there second derivative is $0$.

Comment: yes but f(x) = 42 isn't a complex function so surely that wouldn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: a convex (differentiable) function always lies above its tangent lines. The tangent line at $c$ is $y=f(c)$ because $Df(c)=0$. Therefore $f(x) \geq f(c)$ for every $x$.

Comment: would i not need a strict inequality to be able to say that f(c) is a local minimum?

Comment: Well, it depends on your definition. I never use a strict inequality to define local minima or maxima.